# Accessing Classroom Guardian email addresses

Tags: google-classroom

I am a teacher trying to access guardian emails through the Classroom API to send out periodic progress reports and warnings.  It appears that guardian email addresses are only available to domain administrators.  Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-guardians#who_can_manage_guardians) that answers your question.

> **Who can manage guardians**
>
> The following table describes the actions that can be performed with
>   respect to guardians, according to the type of user currently
>   authenticated:
>
> [image]

See the note:

> *Guardian's email addresses are accessible only by **domain admins**.*

Comment: I would append that a script could be written which uses Domain Admin-level scope privileges to iterate over each student in a given course and get guardian email addresses.  Sending out those emails without prior consent could be considered spammy, even though teachers sending home physical notes have long been accepted. Ahh, the digital world...